# Arquillian with Glassfish V4

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, glassfish, jboss-arquillian, glassfish-4

There is an official, "Arquillian GlassFish Embedded 3.1", plugin.  Should this work with Glassfish V4, or is it a headache in the making?  Is there some other way to test Glassfish V4 with Arquillian?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Latest 3.1 container adapter (CR4) should work with 4.x without any problems, as indicated on [this blog entry](http://arquillian.org/blog/2013/05/02/arquillian-container-glassfish-1-0-0-CR4/).

Comment: I read that blog post and never noticed the bit about GF4.  As an aside note, my tests are working properly with GF4 too.  Thanks!

Comment: It does say clearly at feature request: "ARQ-1293 - Add Support for GlassFish 4.x series"